# Pieces of pie eaten using bash

Tags: bash, cgi

I'm trying to create a script where the user determines the amount of people they want in the query string. Within the number they specified I want them to randomly get a number within 4 printed back.

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 
for i in $(seq 1 "$QUERY_STRING")
pieEaten= $(( ( RANDOM % 4 )  + 1 ))
echo $pieEaten
```

I am using my own machine as a server so I should be able to put http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/pieceofpie.sh?6, but that is only displaying the query string. Ultimately I want to display the results of each using a pie with sections eaten out of it depending on the number. I am using gedit if that makes any difference.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 
pieEaten=$(( ( RANDOM % 4 )  + 1 ))
echo $"<h1>$pieEaten</h1>"
```

Above is the working modified code that displays a random number (1-4). How do I get it so I can display more using the query string?

Comment: That snippet of code is incomplete. Try running that by hand or running it through http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see the problems. If that's not the exact code you are testing then you need to correct the post. You should probably also ensure that the script has execute permissions.

Comment: @amy1313745 Read a shell scripting tutorial.

Comment: `do;done`